# Is there a single word for "fear of duplicates?"

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

I'm designing a data structure that disallows inserting the same element twice, and I want to give it a name. Is there a single word for "fear of duplicates?" "Dupliphobia" sounds wrong.

Comment: Phobophobia, obviously.

Comment: Geminiphobia comes close.

Comment: Xerophobia, obviously!

Comment: Etymologically speaking, it ought to be *homophobia*, but I suppose that's out...

Comment: You don't need to invent artificial words. Just say it has unique elements.

Comment: The Hash Set data structure doesn't allow duplicate items.  As does the Dictionary.

Comment: @GoldenDragon No set does.

Comment: @GoldenDragon they do allow inserting the same element after removing it once, which my data structure does not. It keeps a history of ever inserted elements.

Comment: "dupliphobia!" I spit coffee all over my keyboard when I read that one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: _Diplodocus_? (name of a huge dinosaur which has the word "double" in it (from Greek _diploos_). [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=diplodocus)

Comment: @Hot Licks: cute, but xero means dry, not duplicate; xerography is copying with dry toner rather than wet ink.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - Yeah, I know, but I just couldn't resist.

Comment: @Hot Licks Puns needn't obey zombie rules.

Comment: I think it would be funnier for there to be multiple words for such a fear. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about ***antigrafíphobia***? From Greek word [αντιγραφή • (antigrafí)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B1%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%B3%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%86%CE%AE), “act of copying")+phobia.

For more please see: http://www.wordreference.com/gren/%CE%B1%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%B3%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%86%CE%AE

Comment: I like it! But shouldn't that be antigraphiphobia, in the interest of consistency in rendering phi?

Answer (score 0):

How about "[uniquified](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uniquify)"? To uniquify something in the computational sense is to ensure uniqueness of its elements.

Answer (score -1):

The fear of duplication is called ***Clonophobia***.

Comment: This answer needs help -- can you cite a reliable source for the information.